# Tcl upvar and uplevel in performance

Tags: performance, tcl, upvar, uplevel

Let's say I have a variable which is one level up, which I just want to query its' value. I have two options:
`uplevel { set var_name }`
Or:
`upvar var_name`
If I need to query the variable just once, and not change it, which one should be faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find that `upvar` is probably faster for this. Not necessarily, but most likely. (If you're worried about performance, `time` the alternatives.)
Note that they will both necessarily have to resolve the variable name; that's a cost that's going to be borne anyway. But the version with `upvar` doesn't involve moving code between contexts, so it is likely to be faster.

FWIW, when I try with the example below, my intuition is correct. (The key is that one uses the `upvar` bytecode opcode; the other does `invokeStk`, which is slower because that's the general command dispatcher and has a bunch of overhead necessary for other purposes.)

```
% proc foo {y} {set x 1; bar $y}
% proc bar {y} {upvar 1 x x; list $x $y}
% foo 2
1 2
% time {foo 2} 10000
17.8188412 microseconds per iteration
% proc bar {y} {set x [uplevel 1 {set x}]; list $x $y}
% foo 2
1 2
% time {foo 2} 10000
25.4614022 microseconds per iteration
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [`timerate`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/timerate.htm) for this kind of micro-benchmarking:

```
% namespace import ::tcl::unsupported::timerate
% timerate -calibrate {}
0.03257451263357219 µs/#-overhead 0.032807 µs/# 59499506 # 30481304 #/sec
% proc foo {y} {set x 1; bar $y}
% proc bar {y} {upvar 1 x x; list $x $y}
% timerate {foo 2} 10000
0.437240 µs/# 21285016 # 2287075 #/sec 9306.651 net-ms
% proc bar {y} {set x [uplevel 1 {set x}]; list $x $y}
% timerate {foo 2} 10000
0.612693 µs/# 15497439 # 1632137 #/sec 9495.179 net-ms
```

(Answer holds, clearly: Use `upvar`).